# Unable to insert image in latex on Windows 10 ,getting error- ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `.jpg' not found: using draft se

Tags: graphics, miktex, texmaker, epstopdf

I have used the following packages-

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{array} %enables, for table columns, m{width} and b{width} (only p{width is available without it})
\usepackage{booktabs} %for top, middle and bottomline
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{〈}{\langle}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\makeindex
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2cm}{2cm}
```

The code used is

```
\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{class_diagram1.jpg}
    \caption{Proposed data model for Remote Health framework }
  \label{fig:figclassdia1}
\end{figure*}
I am getting the following error.
```

**! Package pdftex.def Error: File `class_diagram1.jpg' not found: using draft se**
I have seen that this topic has already been discussed with the solution of adding package epstopdf.. but I am unable to complete the said procedure on Windows 10 with shell etc
After this , I included the epstopdf package, but still getting the same error, kindly help...

Comment: If latex can't find it is probably not  there or the name is wrong. Check carefully the name of the file. E.g if you are using the right underscore.

Comment: unrelated but also also check your packages, no document written after 1994 should be using the newlfont package, fancyheadings is similarly obsolete (replaced by fancyhdr that you also load) only load ucs if you absolutely need it for compatibility with older documents using it. epstopdf woul not help with jpg files. make sure the file is in the folder from wheer you start pdftex (which may not be the folder with your tex document)

Comment: Thanks a lot to all. Let me try this.